# update MySql if table exist otherwise insert without using duplicate

Tags: mysql

i want to update the statement if user exist otherwise insert new column

but i cant use unique as there are 2 conditions the user id and user date

I am trying to do something like this

```
SELECT 
IF (EXISTS(
        SELECT id FROM `attendance` 
        WHERE student_id = 7 AND date = '2021-10-04'), 
           (UPDATE attendance SET attendance.attendance = 0 WHERE student_id = 7 AND date = '2021-10-04'), 
           "INSERT QUERY");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using your code like this

```
 SELECT IF(condition, value_true, value_false) AS [column_name]
Else (insertQuery)
```

Should work :)

Comment: What about Update query? I want to update the query if it exists and insert New if it doesn't